# Is it ok to skip validation of TLS validation if the request's host is targeting localhost?

Tags: tls, certificates, http

I'm writing a canary for monitoring which will be deployed to the same host as the monitored application. The underlying application validates certificates for incoming requests and validates that the cn is coming from a specific domain.

The easiest way around for me is to skip cert validation if the host is localhost in the request. I was wondering what security implications this has. Are people able to spoof the host field of a request to be "localhost" when they curl to the DNS routing to the host?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Security SE. This is an interesting question.

Comment: I guess you are mixing 2 layers here: By the "host field" you mean the HTTP host header? If so, by then TLS has already happened. Maybe you could check for the source IP, which can not be spoofed in a TCP connection? But I let others answer about that.

Answer (score 1):

Not for localhost, yes for loopback addresses. "localhost" is just a hostname; by default it's present in the HOSTS file (almost certainly pointing to 127.0.0.1) but this isn't actually always the case! At least some number of Macs back in 2017 (last time I ran into the issue) were missing the HOSTS entry, which means attempting to connect to "localhost" sent out a DNS query. Since DNS is unsecured, anybody on the network could respond; the *expected* response contains a loopback address such as 127.0.0.1, but an attacker could potentially send anything they want. Thus, your client could attempt to connect to "localhost" at an external IP address over an actual network interface, thinking it's the name of some other computer on the network or even the Internet.

One protection you might have in that case is TLS certificate validation. Because no public CA will issue a cert for "localhost", and because no other machine's private CA's signature will be trusted by your client, you should never get back a trusted cert for "localhost" unless it's a local private CA or explicitly-trusted self-signed cert. That can complicate validation somewhat, but you shouldn't just *skip* validation.

---

Of course, with that said, please everybody stop using loopback for IPC! It's way less secure than approximately any other IPC mechanism you might use, and while TLS patches that somewhat it does so at the cost of adding a *lot* of complexity. (It's also less performant, probably even *without* TLS much less with it, though admittedly not in a way that matters.) Unless you're testing the development build of a network server app of some sort (possibly a web app or game server), it makes very little sense for two processes to routinely communicate with one another over loopback, and there's probably a better way to do it. Local (Unix domain) sockets, named pipes, anonymous pipes, shared memory sections plus named mutexes, mapped files, or any of the large host of platform-specific options are all better ideas.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to use the network stack in your setup, future scaling for example. I do agree you should use full tls on it (with self signed certs not really a problem). But if it stays o. The box I would use Unix sockets to kiss it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your question boils down to how your web server will respond if an 'attacker' were to make a TLS connection to your web server from a remote host, then make an HTTP request, with `localhost` specified as the host.  The simplest way to determine how your web server will respond in this case is the run a test simulating this case.  We can use `openssl s_client` to do this.

I don't know the particulars of your site and your web server, so I'll work through an example using `security.stackexchange.com` instead.  `security.stackexchange.com` resolves to several IP addresses, one of them being 151.101.193.69, so I'll use this IP for this example.

Start by using `openssl s_client` to open a TLS connection to 151.101.193.69 on port 443:

```
openssl s_client -connect 151.101.193.69:443
```

openssl responds with some information about the certificate served by the web server, and the TLS connection.  Next, type the following line, and hit enter:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Then type the following line and hit enter twice:

```
HOST: localhost
```

You'll see that the server responds with an HTTP 500 error, `Domain Not Found`.  In contrast, if you enter following line in the last step above, the server responds with a HTTP 200 successful response.

```
HOST: security.stackexchange.com
```

You ought to be able to run a similar test on your web server to see how it responds in both cases.

*A note about SNI:  Note that in the above example, we did not provide any SNI information in the `opensssl s_client` command.  We can see that the certificate served by the web server is for *.stackexchange.com.  This indicates that either *.stackexchange.com is the only site configured on the web server, or *.stackexchange.com is the site the web server defaults to if no SNI information is provided. If you have SNI configured on your web server, so that your web server can serve multiple sites via TLS, then you may want to test how it responds for each site.  You can do this using the `-servername` option with `openssl s_client`.

Comment: The cert used by Stack (from LE) has *.stackexchange.com in CommonName, but that is no longer used; the SAN extension has 25 names. Older versions of OpenSSL did not provide SNI by default, but 1.1.1 does and has been out 3 years -- and is the only 1.x version still freely supported upstream -- so many systems now have it. Also your instructions send the request header with LF not CRLF as specified in the HTTP standards; while most servers will Postelianly accept this, using `-crlf` is better.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, as always thanks for the helpful tips.  +1.